# Light-box external link issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

My light-box  code looks like the one below  I'm trying to make the the 2 words sentence "see website" to link to an external website but it rather messes up the whole thing.

```
<li><a href="images/huelarge.png" title="XHTML | Javascript | Jquery | Design | Logo | <a href="siterpie.com">See website"</a>/>
   <a href="images/huelarge.png"><img src="images/huethumb.jpg" alt="" width="314" height="157" /></a></a></li>
<li>
```

The link to the website proper is [this](http://www.siteripe.com/portfolio.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from your website

```
 <li><a href="images/huelarge.png" title="XHTML | Javascript | Jquery | Design | Logo "/>
      <a href="images/huelarge.png"><img src="images/huethumb.jpg" alt="" width="314" height="157" /></a></a></li>
    <li>
```

The problem is because you close twice  inside a link.

Here's the corrected code :

```
 <li><a href="images/huelarge.png" title="XHTML | Javascript | Jquery | Design | Logo "/><img src="images/huethumb.jpg" alt="" width="314" height="157" /></a></li>
```

Comment: Just as in my question, I'd like it to it to link to an external link via the 2 word sentence "See Website." The link was meant to show how it works normally before I added the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% what your going for, but your HTML is a bit messed up, the title of your first `<a>` is including `<a href="siterpite.com` as part of it.

Maybe try

```
    <li>
       <a href="images/huelarge.png" title="XHTML | Javascript | Jquery | Design | Logo |" /></a>
       <a href="siterpie.com">See website</a>
       <a href="images/huelarge.png"><img src="images/huethumb.jpg" alt="" width="314" height="157" /></a>
   </li>
```